# Conditional List itemtemplate or datatemplate in WPF

Tags: wpf, view

This may be an obvious question, but I think there may well be multiple ways to implement it, so not only will this be useful to me, hopefully it will be useful to others.

Essentially I'm looking for the best way to implement a list view that can accept different types of objects and then renders them with the appropriate item/data template for that object.

So for example... we have a standard product list view, and when we view different categories the business has decided it would like to show a different item template style for each different category.

The main reason for asking this here, is to avoid a nasty hacky solution and discover a good clean method instead.

Hopefully I've provided enough information, let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just specifying `DataTemplates` in the `Resources` with the respective [`DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx) is enough, e.g.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <!-- Do NOT set the x:Key -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Employee}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Blue"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Machine}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model}" Foreground="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

[image: Screenshot]

*(Note that [`DataTemplate.DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx) can also be used for implicit XML data templating (see docs), the property type for that reason is **not** `System.Type`, so unlike in `Style.TargetType` you have to use [`x:Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322.aspx) to reference a CLR-type. If you just enter a string it will not be converted to a type.)*

You might also want to look into [`CompositeCollections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx), to get clean merged lists of varying types.

---

Sample data i used:

```
ObservableCollection<Employee> data = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(new Employee[]
{
    new Employee("Hans", "Programmer")      ,
    new Employee("Elister", "Programmer")   ,
    new Employee("Steve", "GUI Designer")   ,
    new Employee("Stephen", "GUI Designer") ,
    new Employee("Joe", "Coffee Getter")    ,
    new Employee("Julien", "Programmer")    ,
    new Employee("John", "Coffee Getter")   ,
});
ObservableCollection<Machine> data2 = new ObservableCollection<Machine>(new Machine[]
{
    new Machine("XI2",    String.Empty),
    new Machine("MK2-xx", String.Empty),
    new Machine("A2-B16", String.Empty),
});
CompositeCollection cc1 = new CompositeCollection();
cc1.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = data });
cc1.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = data2 });
Data = cc1;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. If you had a really large set of different items, can you think of a way that would make this cleaner?

Comment: What do you mean? What is "unclean"?

Comment: If you have a very large number of items, you will have a very large list of DataTemplate nodes in your template, I was wondering if there was a strategy to manage this maintenance issue.  (Don't worry too much, this is a hypothetical for my case, I was asking for later reference)

Comment: You could possibly split and refactor it into various ResourceDictionaries and merge them at some point, but i have not encountered such issues before so i cannot give you any clear advice on that.

Comment: Code copied as as and with modification does not display anything at all (only empty ListView). Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @javajavajavajavajava: Are you familiar with [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)? Because you can't just copy my code and expect it to work. (see also: [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx))

Comment: Great, but one more question:  How can, in a `DataGrid` application, this: `<DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"`  refer to TWO instances of `DataTemplate`  for each data type ? Probably really simple, but this is a complete mystery to me

Comment: @Roland: Is the cell template still necessary if you have implicit data templates? If so, just put `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>` into it and it should apply templates defined by type in some parent's resources.

Answer (score 13):

One option is to create a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) in your code:

```
public class QueueDisplayDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
    {

        var listBoxItem = item as JobQueueListBoxItem;
        var resourceName = String.Empty;
        switch (listBoxItem.JobQueueListBoxItemType)
        {
            case JobQueueListBoxItemType.QueuedJob :
                resourceName = "DataTemplateQueuedJob";
                break;
            case JobQueueListBoxItemType.TransferWorker :
                resourceName = "DataTemplateTransferWorker";
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("There is no corresponding list box template for {0}", listBoxItem.JobQueueListBoxItemType));
        }
        var element = container as FrameworkElement;
        return element.FindResource(resourceName) as DataTemplate;
    }
}
```

This would then be declared in your XAML as a resource

```
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:QueueDisplayDataTemplateSelector x:Key="QueueDisplayDataTemplateSelector" />
```

And then you would assign this to you list box:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxContents}" 
             ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource QueueDisplayDataTemplateSelector}"
             >
```

Comment: Yes, this is probably how I would've hacked it, I think the `x:type` is cleaner, both suffer a bit with a large set of alternative items.

Comment: This is not necessarily a hack, `DataTemplateSelector` is a "proper" property for a reason, if you only differentiate based on type it's redundant but using selectors you can apply different templates to objects of the same type for example.

Comment: To justify the use of the word "hack", I'm saying it due to the use of a `case` instead of using polymorphism to manage the template selection.

Comment: I doubt that the internal mechanism of WPF does anything other than looking at the type and getting the respective DataTemplate from the dictionary, after all there is no inherited method attached to the data-objects which could provide it. It's not that different, but it has less room for error i guess.