# Selecting a data template based on type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datatemplate

I've declared the following types:

```
public interface ITest { }
public class ClassOne : ITest { }
public class ClassTwo : ITest { }
```

In my viewmodel I'm declaring and initializing the following collection:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ITest> Coll { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ITest>
    {
        new ClassOne(),
        new ClassTwo()
    };  
}
```

In my view I'm declaring the following `ItemsControl`

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Coll}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:ClassOne">
            <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:ClassTwo">
            <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Blue" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

What I expect to see is a red square followed by a blue square, instead what I see is the following:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you're actually wanting [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @ChrisW. Directly from that link: _"... create a DataTemplateSelector when you have more than one DataTemplate for the same type of objects and you want to supply your own logic to choose a DataTemplate to apply based on the properties of each data object. **Note that if you have objects of different types you can set the DataType property on the DataTemplate**."_

Comment: Sorry dude, was thinking [ItemTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I probably shouldn't be on here anyway, first nice day out since winter and my mind is elsewhere, I don't think I even actually looked at the whole question lol. Spring fever, cheers.

Comment: You can also use DataTemplateSelector for that. [MSDN ref.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Stackoverflow ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5644533/1848489)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your issue might be caused by finnicky workings of XAML. Specifically, you need to pass `Type` to `DataType`, but you were passing a string with the name of the type.

Use `x:Type` to decorate the value of `DataType`, like so:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Coll}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ClassOne}">
            <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ClassTwo}">
            <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Blue" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Works perfectly thanks, you omitted the curly braces however ({x:Type local:ClassOne}). Any idea why what I was using wasn't working?

Comment: @kyriacos_k Yours wasn't working because the `DataTemplate.DataType` property is of type `object` (as opposed to e.g. `Style.TargetType`, which is of type `Type`). Hence `local:ClassOne` is interpreted as string and not implicitly converted to `Type`.

Comment: `x:Type` acts just like `typeof()` operator, so you pass in to `DataType` a `Type` instead of a name of your class. - even though [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states it takes `object` and examples don't use `x:Type`

Comment: can this be done in uwp same way ?